# Android loading in images of with different dpi, some do not appear

Tags: android

I'm loading external images from a url, which they are all the same resolution. However, the images that are below 100dpi do not appear. The rest are 100 dpi and they do appear.

I can't wrap my head around this dpi resolution concept, and why I can't use these images even though they are the same resolution at the others.

I've added two test images. Could someone try to add these images externally to imageViews? I want to see if you are able to display them.

http://bloggr.geespot.ca/offbroadway-poster.jpg
http://bloggr.geespot.ca/eppleworth.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like dpi was not the issue after all. The cause was probably the way it was encoded, which I'm not sure how it was done. But I ran it through photoshop and all is fine now.